# Ogr2Ogr exported this boundary 90 degrees incorrectly

Tags: shapefile, sql-server, export, ogr2ogr

I've got some `GEOGRAPHY` data in my Sql Server 2008. I wish to export it as a shapefile (so I can import it into QGIS) and when I do, it's rotated 90 degrees to the left and then flipped 180 degrees to the right.

### Command line

```
C:\>ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "C:\temp\test.shp" "MSSQL:server=dbserver; database=xwing; uid=xwing; pwd=dbpwd"
            -sql "SELECT OriginalBoundary FROM Geography Boundaries where LocationId = 18561"
            -overwrite
            -lco "SHPT=POLYGON"
```

### Boundary is Sql Server 2008

[image]

### Boundary loaded into QGIS after using Ogr2Ogr

[image]

/me sad panda.

Comment: Hint: the polygon has not been rotated, it has been *reflected* by interchanging the coordinates.

Comment: @whuber Cheers. Er.. that makes no sense to me because I have no background in GIS and similar tech. I've tried googling for 'what is a reflected polygon' and similar keywords, but I'm coming up blank. Can you provide some more information/links about this concept, please?

Comment: MS SQL Server Spatial *used* to reverse their `geography` coordinates as (Y X), then they revised this to (X Y). I wonder if this is a relic of those beta days? What do you get from `ogr2ogr --version`?

Comment: Pure: GIS software (and all software dealing with spherical coordinates) is schizophrenic, because nobody can agree on whether (x,y) is (latitude, longitude) or (longitude, latitude).  Mixing up perfectly good coordinates in this way has the effect of *reflecting* the image. You can confirm this by drawing the coordinate graticule on your second image: I bet it looks like it goes from 41.35 to 41.39 *east longitude* and 73.56 to 73.59 degrees *south latitude.*  When you see this phenomenon, you know you will have to persuade either the producer or consumer of your data to switch coordinates!

Comment: @MikeToews : GDAL 1.8.1, released 2011/07/09

Comment: @MikeToews : How do you fix that? I assumed the correct way was to force the output to a standard (geom.STAsBinary()) but that produces too many errors on my side "ERROR 1: GetNextRawGeature(): Corrupt data"

Comment: I can't remember if or how I fixed this :(

Comment: @Pure.Krome It's possible to fix this issue with GDAL >= 1.10.0 compiled with SQLite and SpatiaLite

Answer (score 1):

Because the coordinates are swapped, it's convenient firstly to write an OGR VRT file (e.g. swapped_boundaries.vrt) wrapping the datasource:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="swapped_boundaries">
        <SrcDataSource>MYSQL:xwing,user=uuu,password=ppp,host=localhost,port=3306,tables=GeographyBoundaries</SrcDataSource>
        <SrcSql>SELECT OriginalBoundary FROM GeographyBoundaries WHERE LocationId = 18561</SrcSql>
        <GeometryType>wkbPolygon</GeometryType>
        <GeometryField encoding="WKT" field="OriginalBoundary"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

and then swap the coordinates passing through SpatiaLite (GDAL >= 1.10.0 compiled with SQLite and SpatiaLite):

```
ogr2ogr adjusted_boundaries.shp swapped_boundaries.vrt -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT SwapCoords(geometry) FROM swapped_boundaries"
```